# Java, VisualVM : Setting up VisualVM properly for Java8 based webapps

Tags: linux, configuration, monitoring, java, profile

I have a Java based webapp which I have deployed on one of our server. Sometimes the JVM died because of out-of-memory error. The application is kinda heavy as it uses Cometd(Push mechanism) heavily and some columns are encrypted. For this, I decided to monitor the application, but for some reason, VisualVM wont show sampling and CPU usage. It says that the JVM is not supported.

The 2nd problem I am having is that the update  time of VisualVM is too slow. I want to decrease the intervals between which it monitors, but no luck finding that option as well.

I am running Debian Wheezy, 64 bit and Java8-64bit. The application-container is Apache tomcat and DB is Postgres. Jstatd is already started. I am new to profiling and monitoring, any help would be nice.

Here are the screenshots. Kindly have a look.

Thank you.

*Update*

Here is the updated screenshot of how it looks without the config mentioned below:

[image: Screenshot]

And my catalina.sh has some server config like :

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=portnumer -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

Here is after the above configuration with the new GC :

[image: Updated screenshot after new GC]

Comment: I cannot even call Perform GC or Heap Dump.

Comment: Take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755819/cpu-and-profiling-not-supported-for-remote-jvisualvm-session and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417976/jvisualvm-memory-sampling-remote-applications-are-not-supported

Comment: @FedericoSierra : Thank you very much for your help, the first link was useful to configure JMX. I just want to understand how to understand as to which graph is good and which is bad. I have updated main post and put the screenshots of one with default GC and one with the config I posted. I would like to hear any recommendations or suggestions you have. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to target JVM application works for me:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

Comment: you might want to explain what exactly the command does and why you think  does help the OP

Comment: I don't know why but works for me! +1